# How to combine Blazor Component Modal Prompts so I only need to have one for all validations

Tags: components, blazor

I have defined a blazor component that handles error prompts. If I need to display an error prompt I do the following.

```
@if (NoCharacterName)
{

    <PromptModalComponent OnModalChange="NoCharacterName_Response"
                      messageTitle="Warning!"
                      message="Please enter a name for your character"
                      Type="warning"
                      ConfirmButtonText="Continue"
                      NoCancelButton="True"
                      @ref="@modalPrompt"></PromptModalComponent>
}

@if (NoSexSelected)
{

    <PromptModalComponent OnModalChange="NoSexSelected_Response"
                      messageTitle="Warning!"
                      message="Please select a sex for your character"
                      Type="warning"
                      ConfirmButtonText="Continue"
                      NoCancelButton="True"
                      @ref="@modalPrompt"></PromptModalComponent>
}

@if (NoBookInUse)
{

    <PromptModalComponent OnModalChange="NoBookInUse_Response"
                      messageTitle="Warning!"
                      message="Please Select a book to use"
                      Type="warning"
                      ConfirmButtonText="Continue"
                      NoCancelButton="True"
                      @ref="@modalPrompt"></PromptModalComponent>
}
```

Can this be done and I only have one of the modal components listed? Therefore I can update the message, messageTitle, and other parameters without having to have a component for each possible warning?

Comment: The context for these modals is missing.  What validation infrastructure are you using to generate the messages?  What triggers display of the modals?  What happens if there's `NoBookInUse` and `NoSexSelected`?

Comment: They are triggered by flipping the conditions of the if statements to true. The modals appear and will disappear when I click on the continue button of the modal. This flips the conditional back to false. The modal are setup to appear if this component is present.

Comment: Great, but who flips the condition?  All you're code shows us is a bunch of if statements that open dialogs. No Context - without it no one knows how to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<T>` and create a `foreach` where you render each modal.

Example:

```
@foreach (var validationError in ValidationErrors)
{
    <PromptModalComponent OnModalChange="@validationError.OnChangeEvent"
                      messageTitle="@validationError.Title"
                      message="@validationError.Message"
                      Type="@validationError.Type"
                      ConfirmButtonText="@validationError.ConfirmButtonText"
                      NoCancelButton="@validationError.HasCancel" />
}
```

Can't give an example of `@ref="@modalPrompt"`, because I do not know how this object is used.

---

Although, my opinion this is not user friendly. I would create one modal to list all validation errors, which also simplifies your code. But only if modals are some requirement.

But if it is not required, use `DataAnnotations` and `EditContext` with the `EditForm` component containing `DataAnnotationsValidator` and `ValidationSummary` or `ValidationMessage` components and show these validation errors as the user edits the form.

You can also create custom validation using `DataAnnotations` and `EditContext`.

On top of this you can also create custom attributes inheriting the `ValidationAttribute` class to further automate your validation needs.

Comment: I think I might go with the one modal but it has all my validation errors. A modal is a requirement as I want a nicer looking prompt or warning. Thank you for the help!